# CSS overflow hidden with absolute position

Tags: html, css

I want to absolute position an image that I will be moving around in a div and want anything that extends outside the div to be clipped. Here is an example of the problem:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div style="width: 500px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 50px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black; background: gray;">On top of image.</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 250px; z-index: -1;"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/worldcupfinale10-hp.gif" /></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I want the right edge of the logo to not display. Ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the image's container is positioned absolutely, it is outside of the flow of the "containing" div.

Your choices are to either position relatively or to adjust the dimensions of the absolutely-positioned div, dynamically, with jQuery.

Comment: OK, I was afraid of that. Thanks!

Comment: Hm what about this example `<div style="width: 120px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden; position:absolute; left: Npx; top: Mpx;">
   <div style="position: relative; width: 120px; height: 600px; top: 0px; left: -120px;"></div></div>` is there any reason for the inside div not to hide. Experiencing this behaviour in Safari for windows and Opera
</div>

Comment: This is not correct. Adding overflow:hidden; to your parent container will make the absolutely positioned element inside it not show outside .

Comment: @MartinAndersson, When replying to a comment, please use the `@user-name` address.  This both clarifies what you are referring to *and* alerts the specified user.  See ["Replying in comments", here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @BrockAdams he wasn't replying to a comment though, he was commenting on an answer.

Answer (score 121):

Try adding `position: relative` to your outer div. This will position the image relative to that div (honoring the overflow style) instead of relative to the page.

**Example:**

```
<html>
<body>
  <div style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 50px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black; background: gray;">On top of image.</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 250px; z-index: -1;"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/worldcupfinale10-hp.gif" /></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See it on [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/hifajigoqa/edit?html,output)

Comment: But then it's not positioned relative to the page anymore.

Comment: If the image is suppose to "move around in the div" why would you want it relative to the page?  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: adding `position: relative;` directly to the `body` element also works fine!

Comment: @Dahou according to the question, the inner div should clip the image. Making the body position: relative does not do that.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. for tailwind users add `relative overflow-hidden` to parent.

Answer (score 2):

Move the position absolute to the image, then add the relative to the parent container. Worked for me in a similar situation.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div style="width: 500px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 50px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black; background: gray;">On top of image.</div>
    <div style="position: relative; overflow:hidden;"><img style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 250px; z-index: -1;" src="http://www.google.com/logos/worldcupfinale10-hp.gif" /></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```