# Why doesn't overflow: hidden work with material icons?

Tags: css, fonts, google-material-icons

In the sample below, why doesn't `overflow: hidden;` work on the tile object?

```css
#tileContainer {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tile i {
  opacity: .25;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 150px;
  left: -10px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="tileContainer">
  <div class="tile">
    <i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>
    <div id="tileContent">
      Stuff goes here.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div id="tileContent">
      Stuff goes here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The desired result is something more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you add `position: relative` to `.tile`. I guess it is because `position: absolute` pulls the element out of the flow of the tile.

Comment: I realized positioning the tile either absolutely *or* relatively fixes the problem... this sucks because the original behavior is what I'm experiencing with my masonry layout even though they are positioned absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `position: absolute;`.
See this answer: [CSS overflow hidden with absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225102/css-overflow-hidden-with-absolute-position).