# Overflow: hidded doesn't work when hiding an absolute positioned div

Tags: css

I just recreated the Dev Ed's hamburger navbar, but it doesn't work as expected. The full code is [here](https://codepen.io/Kirill28/pen/QWwywvL/). I tried to set `position:relative` on the `nav-links` container, but that didn't help. What can I do? (The code works if in the pc chrome, but try the website with the dev tools responsive mode, you'll see that the `nav-links` are visible...) Please help me! Some code (but it doesn't work):

```
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  nav {
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS overflow hidden with absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225102/css-overflow-hidden-with-absolute-position)

Comment: I tried your codepen and didn't see anything weird, what's the result that you called "expected"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  nav {
position:relative;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
```

change the position to fixed and make the nav position relative that should do what your looking for?